# Distance Calculation with a requested set of points

Tags: java, hadoop, distance, esri, geo

I have a requirement to determine the distance from each point (lat/long) to every other point in the submitted collection.  It could be 2 to 200 points.  A formula like Haversine is a requirement.  For example A,B,C would return A-B - x.x meters,  A-C - x.x meters, B-C = x.x meters.

I am considering options like a custom solution in Java  OR  possibly leverage distributed computing like Hadoop / Apache Spark  OR  a tool like a GeoProcessing tool (ESRI/ARCGIS).

Has anyone tackled this requirement before?

Any lessons learned?

Comment: You need to ask specific questions here

Comment: 200 points will require 199 factorial distance calculations, which will take a long time no matter how you do the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For distance in meters between points with (lon,lat) coordinates [note X,Y order] with the Esri Spatial Framework for Hadoop, use  [ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/wiki/UDF-Accessors#st_geodesiclengthwgs84).

[More samples of ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84 can be found in this test script](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/blob/master/hive/test/st-geom-text.sql).

Related Q/A on GIS-SE: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170479/join-on-range-query-using-esris-gis-tools-for-hadoop/#185660

[Disclosure: collaborator.]

update: Java API - [GeometryEngine.html#geodesicDistanceOnWGS84](http://esri.github.io/geometry-api-java/javadoc/com/esri/core/geometry/GeometryEngine.html#geodesicDistanceOnWGS84(com.esri.core.geometry.Point,%20com.esri.core.geometry.Point))